# Why Kivy checkbox active event not work?

Tags: python, user-interface, checkbox, event-handling, kivy

I can not find which is the main event for the checkbox in the kv file.
I tried on_checkbox_active but raise an error.
I tried on_active but does nothing (and do not raise any error)
on_release, on_press but obviously give me an error.

this is my basic test code line: on_active: print("hello")

What is the event that run when click on a checkbox?

thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event raised when the state of the checkbox is changed is `on_active`. If you have a problem with it, post a simple runnable example demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Oh thanks, i found the problem. I used it in a custom Widget. I moved on_active under the base widget that inherits checkbox and now works. A little complicated to do with custom widgets but work. I think it would be useful to improve this thing.